# How do I use parseInt to add two numbers?

Tags: javascript, json, parseint

I'm supposed to use parseInt to add two numbers the user enters, then use my response object to send back the result and display output to the user.

For instance, if the user enters 2 and 3, the server should add these numbers together and send back an object containing the value 5.

Here's what I have tried so far/ have:
**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */   

router.get('/add', function (request,response) {
    console.log('add method called');
    console.log('The parameters are: ', request.query);
    //Attempt 1
   //var parse = parseInt('#operatorA',12);
   // var parse2= parseInt('operatorB',7);

    //Attempt 2
   //var operatorA = $('#operatorA').val();
    // var operatorB = $('#operatorB').val();

    //Attempt 3
    //var a = parseInt(" ") ;
    //var b = parseInt(" ") ;
    //var x = parseInt (a + b);

    //Attempt 4
    //var x = a+b;

    //Attempt 5
    //var a = operatorA this won't work b/c operator a isn't defined here.

    //Attempt 6
    //var a = $('#operatorA').val();
    //var b = $('#operatorB').val();
    //var x = parseInt(a);
    //var y = parseInt(b);

    response.send([
        //Attempt 1
        //parse

        //Attempt 2
    //parseInt(operatorA,operatorB)

        //Attempt 3 & 4
      //  x

        //Attempt 6
        //x + y
    ]);
});
module.exports = router;
```

**Control.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    'use strict';
    console.log('Document loaded in isit320');

    $('#read').click(read);
    $('#readJson').click(callReadJson);
    $('#add').click(add);
    }

    function add() {
        var operatorA = $('#operatorA').val();
        var operatorB = $('#operatorB').val();
        console.log('operators: ', operatorA, operatorB);
        var requestQuery = { operatorA: operatorA, operatorB: operatorB };
        $.getJSON('/add', requestQuery,function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            $('#display').html(JSON.stringify(result));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Not sure where you got those ideas from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: It would be helpful if you could describe the problem you are having and reduce this to the minimum amount of code necessary to reproduce it.  As it stands, you haven't actually asked a question

Comment: Hey billy, sorry I'm still pretty new to stack overflow. The question is how do I add to numbers inputted by the user using parseInt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parseInt is used as parseInt(string, radix) like so:

```
var a = parseInt($('#operatorA').val(), 10);
var b = parseInt($('#operatorB').val(), 10);
response.send([a+b]);
```

Comment: The **radix** parameter is very important when it comes to parseInt and should **always** be used.

Comment: @JonP not with a compliant ES2015 engine, 10 is default since then.